# jQuery how to fix Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm new in Jquery and I want once the user adds new row and give the important information once he clicks on "Ajouter" button it will add on data base then reload the table automatically.
Once i run that I found that the data added successfully to the database however  "tablebqup" does not reload anymore and it I found this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
```

Here is the function to add the new element:

```
    $("#newbq").click(function () {
    var indexadd= $('table#tablebqup tr:last').index() + 1;
    //Now add this row to the table:
    var row='<tr><td></td><td  contenteditable="true"></td><td  contenteditable="true"></td><td  contenteditable="true"></td><td  contenteditable="true"></td><td  contenteditable="true"></td><td colspan="2"> <button id="add'+indexadd+'" class="btn btn-info addbc" name="button">Ajouter</button> </td></tr>';
    $('#tablebqup').append(row);
    $(".addbc").click(function () {
      var nombc=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(1)').html());
      var abrv= ($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').html());
      var sigsoc=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(3)').html());
      var telf=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(4)').html());
      var fx=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(5)').html());
    //  if (nombc=="" || abrv=="" || sigsoc=="" || (telf=="" && fx==""))
    if (nombc=="")
      {
        alert("Rempier toutes les informations de la banque d'abord")
      }
      else {
        $choix=confirm("voulez vous vraiment ajouter la banque");
         if ($choix)
         {
           console.log(nombc);
           $.post(basUrl+'views/component/updtbq.php',
             {
               action:'add_bq',
               nomb:nombc,
               abrvb:abrv,
               sigsocial:sigsoc,
               tel:telf,
               fax:fx,
             }, function(data) {
               alert(data);
             $('#tablebqup').DataTable().ajax.reload();//My problem is here
            });
          }
       }
      });
  });
```

In the fist time one i run it  it showed something like this :

```
“Uncaught TypeError: $(…).DataTable is not a function”
```

To solve it i added the appropriate link and script:

Doing that the error has changed to :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
```

What surprised me that i have used above similar logic I mean use the same:

```
 $('#tablebqup').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

and once I  click another button just to modify information on data base in this way :

```
 $(".modif").click(function () {
     $choix=confirm("voulez vous vraiment sauvegarder les modifications");
     if ($choix)
     {
       var id=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').html());// the value in the 1st column.
       var nombc=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(1)').html());
       var abrv= ($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').html());
       var sigsoc=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(3)').html());
       var telf=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(4)').html());
       var fx=($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(5)').html());
       console.log(id);
       $.post(basUrl+'views/component/updtbq.php',
         {
           action:'update_bq',
           idbc:id,
           nomb:nombc,
           abrvb:abrv,
           sigsocial:sigsoc,
           tel:telf,
           fax:fx,
         }, function(data) {
         $('#tablebqup').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        });
      }
```

That work perfectly without adding any of this two links!!!

Here is the dtail of the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
    at Ga (datatables.min.js:36)
    at M (datatables.min.js:28)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:28)
    at jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
    at Function.map (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.map (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at ma (datatables.min.js:28)
    at e (datatables.min.js:104)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:104)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

Here is my php file:

```
function add_bq()
{
  if((isset($_POST['nomb']))
  &&(isset($_POST['abrvb']))
  &&(isset($_POST['sigsocial']))
  &&(isset($_POST['tel']))
  &&(isset($_POST['fax']))
  ){
    $nomb=trim($_POST['nomb']);
    $abrv=trim($_POST['abrvb']);
    $sigc=trim($_POST['sigsocial']);
    $tel=trim($_POST['tel']);
    $fax=trim($_POST['fax']);
    //Update les banques
    MainController::addBanque($nomb,$abrv,$sigc,$tel,$fax);
   include 'C:/wamp/www/Mini_Prj/views/component/tbbanqueupd.php';
  }
```

and here is the included:"tbbanqueupd.php":

```
<?php
require_once("C:/wamp/www/Mini_Prj/controllers/mainController.php");
$bnqs=MainController::getBanque();
echo'
<div>
<h3>  Mise a jours des banques</h3>
<div >

  <div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="tablebqup" class="tableau table table-fixed table-bordered table-dark table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id Banque</th>
      <th>Nom de la banque</th>
      <th>Abrev </th>
      <th>Siège Sociale</th>
      <th>Tel</th>
      <th>Fax</th>
      <th>Modifier</th>
      <th>Supprimer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <form method="post">
  ';
  $i=0;
foreach ($bnqs as $bnq) {

echo
" <tr>
<td>".$bnq['idbc']."</td>
<td  contenteditable='true'>".$bnq['nomb']."</td>
<td  contenteditable='true'>".$bnq['abrvb']."</td>
<td  contenteditable='true'>".$bnq['sigsocial']."</td>
<td  contenteditable='true'>".$bnq['tel']."</td>
<td  contenteditable='true'>".$bnq['fax']."</td>
<td> <button id='modif$i' class='btn btn-info modif' name='button'>Modifier</button> </td>
<td> <button id='supp$i' class='btn btn-info supp' name='button' onclick='suprimer(this.id)'>Supprimer</button> </td>
</tr>";
$i++;
}
echo'
</form>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="button" id="newbq" >Nouvelle banque</button>
</div>
</div>';
```

I thought that maybe the problem is because i allow the user to not filling all the informations, but i want that it gonna be in this way the user enters just the important field.
How could I solve this problem?Can someone help.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It gives me this error when the number of `td` doesnt match the number of `th`, or when I use `colspan`...

Depending on your css, it could be hard to see. I'd add a border to the table while testing it out...

Comment: Yes you are right to solve that problem I added this line $('#tablebqup tr:last').remove();  cause i added the new line dynamically once the user add want to add new item. The written pb was solved but new one appear:datatables.min.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null

Comment: Please tell me what should i do dor this last error?

Comment: Hard to say... What is the script trying to do at that moment ?

Comment: Well it shows all the lines now exept the added one

Comment: I will add my php file

Comment: When I use `colspan` then this generates such error. I have removed colspan to fix this issue now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A simple mistake, the table header had a column " with no title, but the column did not exist in the table itself. I could not see it missing (because o no title and no borders).

Was helped by looking at the line in the datatable.js which gave the error - was implying a tr was at fault, so looked more carefully at my table and not my overall code

Answer (score 2):

I had correct number of columns in `thead-th` section and `tbody-td` section. There was no colspan added on any `th` or `td` elements but I was getting the same issue. I did some more research and found that I disabled sorting feature on a column number which was not exist in my data table.

Actually I had only 4 columns in my data table while I was trying to disable sorting feature for 6th number column. It was an accident. I forgot to change it. Code was as:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#datatable').DataTable( {
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0,1,6] }
        ],
        responsive: true,
    });
});
```

Then I changed 'aTargets' value, which could be set upto 3 as per my case and correct code was as:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#datatable').DataTable( {
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0,1,3] }
        ],
        responsive: true,
    });
});
```

It worked for me. Happy to share and help others :)

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I don't see the DataTabe initialization, usually placed inside the Document Ready function. So:

- Try to Initialize your table with an explicit configuration for each column ("visible:true" is a dummy setting that just confirms it is visible)
- Add the "datatable" class to your table html. Example:

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var myTable= $('#tablebqup').DataTable({
    columns:[
    //"dummy" configuration
        { visible: true }, //col 1
        { visible: true }, //col 2
        { visible: true }, //col 3
        { visible: true }, //col 4
        { visible: true }, //col 5
        { visible: true }, //col 6 
        { visible: true }, //col 7
        { visible: true }  //col 8 
        ]
    });
});
```

And on the html:

```
<table id="tablebqup" class="tableau table datatable table-fixed table-bordered table-dark table-hover ">
```

**Explanation:**

The "DataTable" initialization method should have the same number of columns on its configuration as the number of `<th>`'s/`<td>`'s on your html.

Wrong example:

```
 //Javascript Code
 var myTable= $('#myTableId').DataTable({
    columns: [
        //any column configuration
        { "bSearchable": false }, //col 1
        { "bSearchable": true },  //col 2
        { "bSearchable": true },  //col 3
        { "bSearchable": false }, //col 4
        { "bSearchable": false }, //col 5
        { "bSearchable": false } //col 6 
    ]
});
```

And the html markup:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>col 1 header</th>
        <th>col 2 header</th>
        <th>col 3 header</th>
        <th>col 4 header</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> data col 1, row 1</td>
        <td> data col 2, row 1</td>
        <td> data col 3, row 1</td>
        <td> data col 4, row 1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So even if the number of `<td>`'s and `<tr>`'s are matching on the html, having more columns configured on the DataTable method will cause this exception to be thrown. In this example, removing the configuration lines for col 5 and col 6 from the DataTable method would fix the error.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but number of columns are being generated dynamically based on selected date range. I have to use like colspan="2" and rowspan="3" also. What would be the solution for that?

Comment: If columns and and rows are being generated dynamically on the DataTable, then you should add some callbacks to add/remove them from the DOM as well