# Datatables: missing page elements (sort, search, next...)

Tags: datatables

I'm setting up my first DataTables page and although the table displays and is formatted, most additional elements are missing (sort cols, search, next/previous...).
I have checked the docs, followed tutorials but am still stuck and all I can find is an unintelligible error in the browserś (Chrome) browser.

My HTML file (gets data from a jinja template):

```
<head>
  <title>Test DataTable</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
  </script>

</head>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{_('Prod Code')}}</></th> 
        <th>{{_('Description')}}</th>          
        <th>{{_('Units')}}</th>
        <th>{{_('Category')}}</th> 
        <th></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      {% for each_product in products %}
      <tr>
        <td> {{ each_product.prod_code }} </a></td>
        <td> {{ each_product.prod_desc }} </td>
        <td> {{ each_product.prod_units }} </td> 
        <td> {{ each_product.prod_Category }} </td>    
      </tr>       
    {% endfor %}  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the screenshot of the page in the browser. The rows change to light grey when I hover over them.

[image]

And here is the screenshot from the error in the browser's console:
[image]

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You have 5 `<th>` heading cells in your header row, but only 4 `<td>` cells in your body rows. That's a mismatch. I guess you need to remove that empty heading. Also see here: [jQuery how to fix Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333369/jquery-how-to-fix-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined) - which is the same as the error you are getting here.

Comment: HI Andrewjames, the extra <th> was the issue. Thanks for noticing!